# Is it possible to use the same image twice in the background property?

Tags: html, css

I am making a navigation list, and I was wondering if there is a way to use the `background` property in CSS to place an image on both sides of the link when the user hovers over it. Here is what I currently have:

```
nav.vertical li a:hover {
  background: #D4CD00 url(wnaderknight.png) right/25px 25px no-repeat;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: See background-position and background-repeat. But if i would have to do this, i would use normal <img> instead

Comment: I will go check that now. How would <img> and make it only show when the user hovered over the link? I should mention that I made [nav.vertical li] display: block

Comment: Yes you can ! ex: 
`background:url(wnaderknight.png) 25px 25px no-repeat,  url(wnaderknight.png) right/100px 100px no-repeat  #D4CD00 ;` color background is to be set with last image :)

Comment: Thank you! This worked great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use multiple backgrounds or pseudos

```css
.bg {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:30px;
  background:url(http://www.icone-gif.com/icone/nature/terre/terre-32.png) right/25px 25px no-repeat,url(http://www.icone-gif.com/icone/nature/terre/terre-32.png) left/25px 25px no-repeat
}
.psdo:before,
.psdo:after {
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:inline-block;
  content:url(http://www.icone-gif.com/icone/nature/terre/terre-32.png)
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="bg"> link with bg image on both sides </a> <br/>
<a href="#" class="psdo"> link with bg image on both sides </a>
```